# Cómo obtener las coordenadas actuales en Vue2Leafet

Tags: vue.js

Tengo un mapa utilizando Vue2Leaflet, el cual intento obtener las coordenadas del mapa cada vez que se dispara el evento dragend (cuando se cambia la ubicación del mapa)

```
<template>
<div id="map" ref="map" style="height: 100vh">
   <client-only>
      <l-map @dragend="getCoords" :zoom=4 :center="[coords.lat, coords.lon]" :options="{zoomControl: false}">
          <l-tile-layer :url="themes.default"></l-tile-layer>
   </client-only>
</div>
```

Intenté acceder al objeto `this.$refs.map` pero no muestra las coordenadas, ¿cómo puedo obtenerlas?

Comment: supongo que quieres el bbox? o la coordenada del centro del mapa?

Comment: Si, quiero las coordenadas del centro del mapa cada vez que el usuario lo mueva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías usar el evento [`update:center`](https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/components/LMap.html#events)

#### Ejemplo:

```
<template>
  <div style="height: 100vh">
    <l-map :zoom="zoom" :center="center" @update:center="centerUpdate">
      <l-tile-layer :url="themes.default"></l-tile-layer>
    </l-map>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { latLng } from "leaflet";
import { LMap, LTileLayer} from "vue2-leaflet";

export default {
  name: "Example",
  components: {
    LMap,
    LTileLayer
  },
  data() {
    return {
      zoom: 13,
      center: latLng(47.41322, -1.219482)
    };
  },
  methods: {
    centerUpdate(center) {
      // AQUI Notifica cuando el centro es actualizado
      console.log(center);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```